# Javascript Search Ranges

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, datetime, range

I have a list of JSON Values

```
[{'start_day':1,'start_hour':1,'end_day':1,'end_hour':2},
{'start_day':1,'start_hour':4,'end_day':1,'end_hour':6}, 
{'start_day':1,'start_hour':9,'end_day':1,'end_hour':11}]
```

Now in Javascript i have a table that lets me add more of these to a table.  I can do that no problem but what I am looking for is.  Is there any code that will allow me to search to make sure a user is not entering an overlapping date time range.  Similar to an SQL Between command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're referring to a 7 days x 24 hours range, creating a table consisting of all values can be useful. The advantage of this is that you don't have to repeat calculations for every new element. Instead, you can add up a counter.

In your case, the counter should always be zero or one (because dates may not overlap, per definition). However, the same functions can *also* be used to determine whether there's an overlap given a set of objects. Then, one of the counters is greater than one.

**Code** (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EtaJE/1/):

```
// Initialize list and variables.
var totalHours = 7*24;
var dates = [];                                // Empty list
for (var i=0; i<totalHours; i++) dates.push(0);// Fill list with zeros

/* @param listi object { start_day ; end_day ; start_hour ; end_hour }
 * @param one   number  Recommended values: 1 (add), -1 (remove)
 */
function addDate(listi, one) {
    one = +one === one ? one : 1; // Make sure that one is a number.

    var listi = list[i];
    if (listi.start_day <= listi.end_day) {
        var start = listi.start_day * 24 + listi.start_hour;
        var end = listi.end_day * 24 + listi.end_hour;
        for (var j=start; j<end; j++) {
            dates[j] += one; // Increase counter by one
        }
    } else {
        var start = listi.start_day * 24 + listi.start_hour;
        var end = listi.end_day * 24 + listi.end_hour;
        for (var j=0; j < end; j++) {
            dates[j] += one; // Increase counter by one
        }
        for (var j=start; j<totalHours; i++) {
            dates[j] += one; // Increase counter by one
        }
    }
}

/*
 * @param object { start_day ; end_day ; start_hour ; end_hour }
 */
function doesDateOverlap(listi) {
    if (listi.start_day <= listi.end_day) {
        var start = listi.start_day * 24 + listi.start_hour;
        var end = listi.end_day * 24 + listi.end_hour;
        for (var j=start; j<end; j++) {
            if (dates[j]) return true; // Not zero, overlapping!
        }
    } else {
        var start = listi.start_day * 24 + listi.start_hour;
        var end = listi.end_day * 24 + listi.end_hour;
        for (var j=0; j < end; j++) {
            if (dates[j]) return true; // Not zero, overlapping!
        }
        for (var j=start; j<totalHours; i++) {
            if (dates[j]) return true; // Not zero, overlapping!
        }
    }
    return false; // At this point: No overlap, so OK.
}


// Parse the values from the JSON list. Example:
var list = [{'start_day':1,'start_hour':1,'end_day':1,'end_hour':2},
            {'start_day':1,'start_hour':4,'end_day':1,'end_hour':6}, 
            {'start_day':1,'start_hour':9,'end_day':1,'end_hour':11}]
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
    addDate(list[i], 1);
}

// Example
if (doesDateOverlap({'start_day':1,'start_hour':1,'end_day':1,'end_hour':11})){
    alert('Overlap!');
}
```

Comment: This works to an extent.  My week ranges from
Sunday 0 to Saturday 6.  What happens if I start a time on Friday 5 and Run it to Tuesday 2.  Ive updated the script accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/EtaJE/1/

Comment: @Deano Updated answer. Note that my hours range from 0 to 23.